# How to enable smooth zoom in Openlayers in default library set?

Tags: openlayers-2

I've compared two Openlayers samples:

- [Online dev example - clientzoom](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html)
- [release dev example - clientzoom](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/clientzoom.html)

First one zooms in smoothly, second one just flashes and shows tiles from next zoom level.

The only difference between those two versions is the library - release dev example (second) uses default multi-file version, while the first one - uses some compiled version (not sure from which tag).

Question is: how to enable smooth zoom in Openlayers 2.12? Or how to enable smooth zooming in any Openlayers version ;)

[Edit]

The fluent zoom feature is included by default in 2.13 library:

- [release dev example for 2.13 - clientzoom](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/examples/clientzoom.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example uses the development version, and the second the latest stable version, which is 2.12.

And the dev version includes the following patch:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/21448d2fd57d3d618a9cff4d1ded6a0e947eec5a

who will be able to use in future version 2.13, I guess.